# JsPlumb connection should not change once it is connected

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jsplumb

I am using JsPlumb in my project.I have to draw a line using it.When the connection has established it should not be movable any more(i.e. connection should be freezed.).Can you please suggest if there is any porperty in jsplumb to stop moving the connection.

Thanks
Vamsi

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are mentioning is about the `detachable` option. While creating connection with `jsPlumb.connect()` set the option `detachable` to `false` so that connections cannot be dragged by their endpoints:

```
jsPlumb.connect({ 
    source:"aThirdElement", 
    target:"yetAnotherElement",
    detachable:false
});
```

With the endpoint declaration you can set it using `connectionsDetachable:false`

```
jsPlumb.addEndpoint('element2', { 
     anchor:"TopCenter",
     connectionsDetachable:false 
});
```

Comment: Hi Pruthi,I alomost resolve the issue.But i am using jsPlumb.makeSource